# Converting Java to iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, converters

Is there any library that can be used to convert Android java code to iOS ? Please if more than one enumerate the advantages.

Comment: Trying to convert Java to iOS is **bad idea**.Just understand the logic that that your code does in Java and write the code by yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [J2ObjC](http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2012/09/j2objc-java-to-ios-objective-c.html) from Google to achieve this.

Comment: a short guide: http://tinyurl.com/m3tzo4s

Comment: How it works ? how to use it ?

Answer (score 6):

There are two nice tools available which will be useful for those who work on both Android as well as iOs

**Java to Objective c converter** click [here](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) to visit.

**Objective c to Java converter** click  [here](https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/) to visit.

Answer (score 3):

check this project from Google http://google-opensource.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/j2objc-java-to-ios-objective-c.html, this is the only one that I here about. I make a few test a time ago and the result was not so good.

Answer (score 2):

use **J2ObjC**

The open-source tool, which automatically converts Java source code into the Objective-C language that is used in native iPhone and iPad apps

Comment: see the details hereb http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/15/google_j2objc_tool/

Answer (score 2):

Yes **J2ObjC**. Google developed.

http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/

http://www.androidcentral.com/google-develops-tool-translate-java-ios-friendly-objective-c-code

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna have a look at [J2Objc](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/).it is an open-source command-line tool from Google that translates Java code to Objective-C for the iOS (iPhone/iPad) platform.