# objective-c code convert for java code

Tags: java, android, objective-c, converters, difference

I have a objective-c code.
but I want to convert to java code.

I know objective-c's *NSData* equals java's *byte[]*.

but I don't know about the equivalent of rest of the keywords.

**Objective-C CODE**

```
    NSData * updatedValue = characteristic.value;
    uint8_t* dataPointer = (uint8_t*)[updatedValue bytes];

    uint8_t flags = dataPointer[0]; dataPointer++;
    int32_t tempData = (int32_t)CFSwapInt32LittleToHost(*(uint32_t*)dataPointer); dataPointer += 4;
    int8_t exponent = (int8_t)(tempData >> 24);
    int32_t mantissa = (int32_t)(tempData & 0x00FFFFFF);

    if( tempData == 0x007FFFFF )
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid temperature value received");
        return;
    }

    float tempValue = (float)(mantissa*pow(10, exponent));                        
    self.tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", tempValue];
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not attempt convert it to Java, *determine what it does and write it in Java*.

A little educated guesswork based on your knowledge of programming should get you a long way to understanding the code. This is a great advantage of programming languages over natural languages, understand programming and you can usually make a good educated guess at the meaning of a fragment of code even if you don't know the language. In natural languages the same simply does not hold, knowing, say, French is little help in reading Hindi!

So let's see, `uint8_t` is probably a type, what type could it be? Well `int` sounds a lot like integer, `8` is probably the size of the integer in bits - it occurs in the second line which also contains the word `bytes`, and the `u` probably means unsigned. So guess that `uint8_t` is an unsigned 8-bit integer. Now look at the other type-like words, do they make sense in the same way?

So what is the code doing? Well you've figure out that `NSData *` is "like" `byte[]`, so what would the code set `flags` to? The first byte in the array maybe? How about `tempData`? Well there is a `32` in the types here, and that is four bytes.

Having got `tempData` what do the code do? Some manipulation which results in `tempValue` which is a `float`. Maybe `float` is a 32-bit floating point number? Which is of course what it is in Java.

However here you're going to hit a wall. If you look up how a 32-bit floating-point number is represented in IEEE 754 - the most common way to represent floating point numbers - you will discover that it is stored in binary with the mantissa being a *faction* (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)).

Now look at the code, `pow(10, exponent)` looks a lot like *10 to the power*, not *2 to the power*. And does the mantissa look like its being treated as a fraction?

So whatever for those 4 bytes you've guessed are being converted into a `float` it looks like either (a) they are not a typical 32-bit float or (b) the Objective-C code is wrong...

So back to the first point - *determine what this code is meant to do and then write it directly in Java*, don't try to convert it.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

You could try

**[Objective c to Java converter](https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/)**

Incase if you need your java code to be converted to Objective C

**[Java to Objective c converter](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/)**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19661440/730807)